# Does this identity have a name? $\sum_{i=0}^{n}a_ib_i=a_n\sum_{j=0}^{n}b_j-\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left((a_i-a_{i-1})\sum_{j=0}^{i-1}b_j\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, soft-question

While doing some work, I discovered the following identity:

> For two sequences $(a_0, a_1, \dots, a_n)$ and $(b_0, b_1, \dots, b_n)$, we have
>
> $$ \sum_{i=0}^{n}a_i b_i = a_n \sum_{j=0}^{n} b_j - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( (a_i-a_{i-1}) \sum_{j=0}^{i-1} b_j \right) $$
>
> **Proof:** Substitute $b_i = \sum_{j=0}^{i}b_j - \sum_{j=0}^{i-1}b_j$ on the LHS. Distribute the multiplication. Modify the index $i \leftarrow i-1$ on the first term. Separate the last element of the
> sum from the first term and combine the remaining sums since they have
> the same bounds. $\square$

Is this widely known or used in a certain domain? Does it have a name?

Comment: I think you are looking for the Abel summation formula written in a different form, known as the [Newton series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series). You can read more about it at the above link.

Comment: summation by parts?

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Thanks! Seems like we've found it. I'll try to connect the dots and answer my own question, unless someone beats me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @Fawkes4494d3, this is one of the forms of summation by parts, also known as Abel's summation formula and specifically Newton series. It is given in this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n f_k g_k &= f_0 \sum_{k=0}^n g_k+ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (f_{j+1}-f_j) \sum_{k=j+1}^n g_k\\
&= f_n \sum_{k=0}^n g_k - \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \left( f_{j+1}- f_j\right) \sum_{k=0}^j g_k, 
\end{align}
$$

The identity provided in the question is equivalent to the second line.